# Determining if German naturalized in South Africa

Tags: germany, 20th-century, naturalization, south-africa

My Grandfather was born in Germany 31 October 1900, in Koningsberg. He came to South Africa 22 July 1930 according to Table Bay stamp in passport.

I have no idea if he became a South African citizen and not sure how to find out if there is a Naturalization certificate. My cousins and I would like to find out if we qualify for passports based on ancestry of my Grandfather.